# Ampersands in AIR system tray tooltip

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have an AIR app that I have developed for a client.

It has a system tray icon with the company name, app name etc, displayed in a tooltip.

This all works very simply except that the client in question has a & in their name.

No matter how I encode this, it never seems to get displayed.

Anyone come across this before, or have any workarounds?

Comment: If `&amp;` doesn't works, then you could try `&&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If & doesn't works, then you could try &&. – splash

**This is the right answer!** I'm using this for a [ContextMenuItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenuItem.html) in Flex 4.5.1. At first I've tried escaping the ampersand with `'&amp;'`, but that doesn't work here.

Best regards,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

If you're directly assigning the tooltip a string of characters sometimes creating a string variable that contains the text you want and assigning that variable to the tooltip will work.  I've used this before under various circumstances, but never for a system tray tooltip.

Comment: No joy on this either. Have just avoided this now, and changed title in tooltip

Answer (score 0):

For me - `&&&` works.